# Change input fields text as a user types in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a function which adds and removes colons as a user types, however the output is being shown outside of the input field hence I am trying to make the input field change as I type. I have the following function which executes on (change).

Here is the code

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (change)="changedInput()" placeholder="MAC address" name="mac_address" required [(ngModel)]="model.mac_address" (blur)="validate()">
  <mat-error *ngFor="let error of errors_by_field['mac_address']">{{error.message}}</mat-error>
  <span>{{formatedMac}}</span>
</mat-form-field>

changedInput() {
  const blocks = this.model.mac_address.match(/.{1,2}/g);
  this.formatedMac = blocks.shift();
  for (const block of blocks) {
    this.formatedMac = this.formatedMac + ':' + block;
  }
}
```

How can I customise this to make the text change in the input as the user types?

Comment: did you try to change `model.mac_address` like you did for `formatedMac`? If you want to do something clean it's not that easy because you have to handle the case when your user uses all the editing tools that an input provides (backspace, text selection and deletion, etc...) and keep the cursor in place

Comment: I tried adding [value]='formattedMac' but it breaks because when nothing is typed in the input its undefined

Comment: why did you use `[value]`? you have `[(ngModel)]` already, it's two-way databinding

Comment: I need to append the formattedMac value to the input the user is typing in, not sure how to do it any other way

Comment: well you used `[(ngModel)]` so everything you type goes in `model.mac_address` and every programmatic modification you make on `model.mac_address` goes into your input. I'll try to make an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used `[(ngModel)]`, so everything you type goes in `model.mac_address` and every programmatic modification you make on `model.mac_address` goes into your input.

Then try this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (change)="changedInput()" placeholder="MAC address" name="mac_address" required [(ngModel)]="model.mac_address" (blur)="validate()">
  <mat-error *ngFor="let error of errors_by_field['mac_address']">{{error.message}}</mat-error>
  <span>{{model.mac_address}}</span>
</mat-form-field>

changedInput() {
  const blocks = this.model.mac_address.match(/.{1,2}/g);
  let formattedMac = blocks.shift();
  for (const block of blocks) {
    formattedMac  = formattedMac  + ':' + block;
  }
  this.model.mac_address = formattedMac;
}
```